# Recommendation for Genesis emulator that can autoload a state

Tags: boot, emulator, homebrew

I'm looking for Genesis Emulator(windows would be nice but *ix would be fine) that can autoload a particular (homebrew) ROM and state on startup, any ideas?

**Edit:**
The homebrew application is a communication tool for a disabled child, not a game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked out easier to alter the ROM itself so that it always started in a particular configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The [RetroCopy](http://retrocopy.com) emulator doesn't autoload the game but there is an option to autoload a state once you load a game.

For other good Genesis/Mega Drive emulators see:

- [Kega Fusion](http://www.eidolons-inn.net/tiki-index.php/?page=Kega)
- [Regen](http://aamirm.hacking-cult.org/www/regen.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Genesis *nix emulator](http://www.squish.net/generator/) and the same program, [with Megadrive support](http://www.squish.net/generator/cbiere/generator/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Gens](http://www.gens.me/). It doesn't autoload a state, although it's quite simple to associate the ROM's file extension with Gens, so that if the ROM were double clicked or if there were a shortcut to the ROM, it would auto-launch Gens.

If the last time you had Gens open, it was fullscreen then the game will open Gens in fullscreen. As far as the state goes, though, I'm thinking you'd be using one of the [F#] keys to manually save before you shut the emulator at the end of a session and loading the state would be as simple as touching the [F#] key assigned to load state.